# rsync via ansible command/shell waits forever when copying from host to remote machine as different ssh user

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy some of my files to a remote machine.
I am using ansible 2.3.1.0 on Lubuntu and the remote machine is CentOS 7.2.
The only catch here is I need to copy the files as a different user to remote machine. 
Here is the playbook with the rsync command

---

```
 - name: Copy files to remote machine as user abc
   shell: rsync -az ~/git/api_test/ --exclude='ansible/' abc@scspa.rtp.openenglab.abc.com:/home/abc/api/
```

However , this command waits forever at the following point.

```
<scspa.rtp.openenglab.abc.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER:root
<scspa.rtp.openenglab.abc.com> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -vvv -C 
-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=root -o 
ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/user/.ansible/cp/2df8c9c6b2 tt 
scspa.rtp.openenglab.abc.com '/bin/sh -c 
'"'"'/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1516965479.47-
49767854925756/command.py; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-
1516965479.47-49767854925756/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
```

The shell command works perfectly fine when i trigger it via the terminal and it runs instantly.

I tried the same with synchronize module of ansible as follows:

```
 - name: Copy files to remote machine as user abc
   synchronize:
    src: ~/git/api_test/
    dest: rsync://lnp@scspa.rtp.openenglab.abc.com:/home/abc/api/
    mode: push
    rsync_opts:
      - "--exclude=ansible/"
```

I am getting the following message

```
"msg": "rsync: failed to connect to scspa.rtp.openenglab.abc.com (10.10.123.22): Connection refused (111)\nrsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(125) [sender=3.1.2]\n", 
"rc": 10
```

I am currently using copy module of ansible but it takes a lot of time to copy file/ check if already copied though this works.

Trying to figure out what am i missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I understand that you want to copy local files to remote machine.

But your `shell` tasks is executed on remote host, not your local one.
And playbook log suggests just that:

```
<scspa.rtp.openenglab.abc.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER:root
```

You may want to delegate the task to your local controller:

```
- name: Copy files to remote machine as user abc
  shell: rsync -az ~/git/api_test/ --exclude='ansible/' abc@scspa.rtp.openenglab.abc.com:/home/abc/api/
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Important basic concept easy to get overlooked. Worked like charm.